# How come Apache retrieves files from the `html` subdirectory when only `/var/www` is specified in `<Directory>` path

Tags: apache, directory, apache-config

I have the following (default) `<Directory>` directive in my `apache2.conf` configuration file:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and the `/var/www` directory contains only an `html` directory with an `index.html` file inside and no `.htaccess` (neither near or in the `html` directory). What default configuration value makes Apache give me files fro the `html` directory? I would have expected that the `DocumentRoot` (if nowhere provided) is the `Directory` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which OS and distro you are using, but my Mint/Ubuntu has `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` which `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html`

Please check if you have the same VirtualHost